# Calling method '_start_suite' of listener 'DataDriver' failed: ImportError: Requirements (pandas, openpyxl)

Tags: python, robotframework

Calling method '_start_suite' of listener 'DataDriver' failed: ImportError: Requirements (pandas, openpyxl) for XLSX support are not installed.
Use 'pip install -U robotframework-datadriver[XLS]' to install XLSX support.

Python Version - 3.7.8
Robot Framework - 6.0.1
Robot Framework Data Driver - 1.7.0

Library     DataDriver     ../Data/PLAC_Dehumidification_SQA_Scenario.xlsx      sheet_name=Automation

Comment: Your error message says what is the root cause and what should you do.

Comment: Trying to do data driven testing from a xlsx file , which has test cases written it with data